# Two textures in the same object (not using assign)

Tags: texturing, uv

I have an ball as an object and i would like to use a plastic like texture (the red one in the picture) and also to add a logo as a image texture. But when i combine the two of them, it's render just one or another. I try to use two different UV maps, or with a mix node, but nothing is working. Here is the image with the image texture applied. [image]

Comment: I found out myself! I forgot to connect the alpha to the fac in the mix node!

Comment: You can't mix two different materials from two different slots using an image texture like that, and you cannot apply two different slots to the same face of a mesh, that is not how texture as masks work.

To mix two different surfaces using a texture either use the texture as a mask to mix two different shaders **inside** the same material, or use the texture as mask to mix two different colors in an *alpha-over* style

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your logo texture is a png image, you might use the transparancy channel, to drive a  color mix node in cycles. The yellow input connections of the mix node have to be connected to the two textures. The alpha output of the logo texture has to be connected to the gray factor input of the mix node.
The transparency will be the trigger to mix the one or the other texture.